# Injecting Grails 2.4.x i18n messages with controller-provided model args

Tags: grails, internationalization

Grails 2.4.4 here. In the [i18n docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/i18n.html) they provide the following example:

```
<g:message code="my.localized.content" args="${ ['Juan', 'lunes'] }" />
```

The problem here is that `'Juan'` and `'lunes'` are hardcoded Strings provided at the *GSP layer*. **But what if we wanted these to be injected - by the controller - as part of the GSP's data model?** For instance:

```
class MyController {
    SomethingService somethingService

    def something() {
        String str1 = somethingService.doSomething() // Might return 'Juan'
        String str2 = somethingService.doSomethingElse() // Might return 'lunes'

        render(view: 'something', model: [ str1: str1, str2: str2 ])            
    }
}

// Inside the GSP:
<h1><g:message code="my.localized.content" args=??? /></h1>
```

Here I need to configure `args` to inject the localized `<g:message />` with `str1` and `str2` from my model (again, provided upstream by the controller). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried: `<g:message code="my.localized.content" args="${ [str1, str2] }" />` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using model variables in the `<g:message>` tag as arguments is the simplest way to accomplish this.

For example:

```
<g:message code="my.localized.content" args="${ [str1, str2] }" />
```